# unrecognized token: "772762303ORDER"

Tags: python, sqlite, bots

Getting error

I get:  unrecognized token: "772762303ORDER"
When I run the following code

```py
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table where Id="+str(id)+"ORDER BY id"):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Because you missed out a space in your string concatenation. You first need `" ORDER BY id"` and the order code in single quotes to make it work, then drop the string concat approach to use parameterized queries

Comment: This is why you bind values to parameters in a query instead of trying to embed strings directly in it. Plenty of examples in the python sqlite documentation.

Comment: @Shawn well, that and escaping inputs to protect your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

space needed

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table where Id="+str(id)+" ORDER BY id"):
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

"ORDER BY Id" doesn't has meaning here, so use

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table where Id=?", [str(id)]):
    print(row)
```